# Stored procedure works on Local host but not on production server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am currently working on an ASP.net based fleet management application. The application fetches the daily exchange rate and allows users to make transactions based on the exchange rate. There transactions are of two kinds
1. Local Currency (exchange rate =1 )
2. USD

I have written a simple select query read exchange rate value from a table in database. This query works when I access it using local host but when I try to access it using the deployed application it doesn't work

The SQL query is

```
SELECT id_exchange_rate, Exchange_rate
FROM NVP_ExchangeRate
WHERE CAST(Exchange_Rate_date as date)=CAST(@date_today as date)
    AND Manual_rate IS NULL
```

It is enclosed inside the following block

```
if (currency_actual == "USD")
{
}
```

Either of the two conditions is failing. 
Can someone help me with this ?
Also, The same application is deployed in 2 QA servers. It is working in both the QA servers.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* In what way does it not work?

Comment: There are 3 database and deployment servers. 
QA server
Dev server
Prod server.

On QA deployment server, the exchange rate is getting populated
On Dev deployment server, the exchange rate textbox is coming blank
On prod deployment server, the exchange rate textbox shows '1' in it.

Same application is being deployed on all 3 servers (With changes in webconfig file)

When I run the application via Local host and connect to QA,Dev and Prod servers, correct value of exchange rate gets populated.

Comment: You are passing in a value `@date_today` into the proc, what s that set to? I'm guessing the production box is set to a different country than the rest of your servers and treats the date value differently (i.e. `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`)

Comment: Wow.
You are correct. I'm from India, My server is in Mexico.

There's a mistake I did though, 
I am passing current date via C#, I think I should be using GETDATE() function in the stored procedure instead.

Comment: Another reason to keep your data stored as the correct type in the first place - dates are dates, not strings...

Comment: You gave me what I needed. 
It's not that the date is in an incorrect format, It's just that I am passing the date using my code, instead of taking it using GETDATE().

Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: My application UI is being operated from India. 
Hence the most recent exchange rate value is for 20th March.

The database is located in Mexico.
when the users in mexico are attempting to read that value, they can't. Because the date is 19th March there.

I don't know if I am able to explain you my issue, but I got my solution thanks to your comment. What you mentioned wasn't the issue, but it helped me solve my problem.
So Thanks !

Comment: @AshishSamant what version of SQL Server are you using? What's the error message? try to add the schema on the table (2-part naming) eg. dbo.NVP_ExchangeRate.and make sure you are on the right database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought that I'd add an answer to my question.

In the first query, I am getting the value of current date from the application (DateTime.Now in c#) and then passing this date to my SQL query. My Application server was based in India. However, my database server was based in Mexico.

So when I use DateTime.Now on an Indian server, it returns the current Indian date. When I take this date and go to my database query which is in Mexico (which is almost 12 hours behind India), the dates don't match as Mexico is almost a day behind us.

The root cause of this issue could be attributed to poor programming on my part.